# Codenameone difference between NetworkConnection setTimeOut and ConnectionRequest settimeout

Tags: timeout, codenameone

I have two questions in Codenameone:

What is the difference between NetworkConnection setTimeOut and ConnectionRequest setTimeout?
How can I handle the case when a timeout has been reached in any case (NetworkConnection or ConnectionRequest)?

Thanks,
Gustavo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global vs. Local.

ConnectionRequest sets the timeout for that specific request, NetworkManager sets the global default.

Comment: Thank you, Shai. After a timeout has been reached, How can I tell to Codenameone that it is time to get data from other place, like the internal Storage? Should I use a try-catch? Can I do this synchronously or asynchronously?